# Rep needed for Edit rights on new sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, stack-exchange, beta-sites

I have just run into the problem of not being able to edit an answer (to add a link) on https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/

Some of the comments on answers/questions seem to be due to people not being able to edit.

As it is a new site with not many users/questions it can take a very long time for someone to get edit rights.

Therefore I think the rep needed for edit rights on new sites should be a lot lower (maybe around the 250 mark).

(It may work having the rep requirements being lower on **new** sites for users that have proved themselves on established sites then for users that don’t have a stackexhange record.)

Answer (score 1):

This is already true.

See:
[Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared)

Specifically:

**Edit other people's posts, suggest tag synonyms**
public beta: 1000 rep
all other times: 2000 rep

Comment: Looking at http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users only 5 users have over 1000 rep, 3 of these are the mods.  I think at least all the users on the top page should be trusted on bicycles.